# Anylogic: Error appearing during model simulation

Tags: anylogic

I tried to run a model in Anylogic, but there is always that appearing error (see picture)
[picture error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMCsz.png)
What does it mean? I have several schedules which control the arriving rates, i checked them already for same setting. The delays are measured in minutes, arrival rates in weeks and months and the simulation runs for 3 months. I have an event for hold: [startevent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkOHF.png) [stopevent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaIZS.png)
Thank you for your help.
Error in the console: [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVVOw.png)
MAin.java: [java_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgOQ3.png)

Comment: Looks like you set some recurring event or Dynamic Event wrongly. Check the console, see where the error originates from, share your model details and help us help you :) Some more tips: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i added some information

Comment: Click on the blue error hyperlink that points to Main.java:426: this will tell you where the error comes from (you need to decipher the code a bit). Either share that part of the model or see if you can solve it from there

Comment: i can`t find the mistake

Comment: screenshot what is shown when you click that error link Main.java:426